# show blank row in power bi for previous day

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

i can't show previous day data with DAX formula "calculate" in power bi.

[image: 1]

i have tried with this formula:
previous_Day_sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[count]),DATEADD('Table'[date].[Date],-1,DAY))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked this issue. this problem is in relation between tables.
if use DimDate and correct relation with table (fact table) this problem is solved.
Here's an example is correct and done.

pervious_day_sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[count]),
(DATEADD(DimDate[Date].[Date],-1,DAY)))

Comment: this answer good for DAX and MDX  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14216788/19434435